# How to generate serial STRING primary key in Database

Tags: database, database-design

My collegues don't like auto generated int serial number by database and want to use string primary key like :

"camera0001"
"camera0002"

As camera may be deleted, I can not use "total nubmer of camera + 1" for id of a new camera.

If you were me, how will you generate this kind of key in your program?

PS : I think auto generated serail number as primary key is OK, just don't like arguing with my collegues.

Comment: Using a string as a primary key is extremely poor practice.  String compares are orders of magnitude slower than integer compares.  However, to the point of your question, what database server are you using? The details of how or if you can do that will depend on the server.

Comment: I am using postgresql.  I tried to explain that "camera0001", "camera0002" ... are as meaningless as 1, 2, ..

But my colleagues just feel it's ridiculous to identify a camera with an auto generated int number.

Comment: This is a comment for myself.  My colleague believe that we should use specified globally unique string as PK for cameras. Like telephone number, it should contains country code, area number, sub area number, and so on.

Again, I am called "near-sighted" because I don't really believe that one day we will connect millions of cameras from everywhere in the world.

But I don't want to be called "near-sighted" any more.  Let the dreamers dream, I will just do what they asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't agree that a sequence number is always the best key. When there is a natural primary key available, I prefer it to a sequence number. If, say, your cameras are identified by some reasonably short model name or code, like you identify your "Super Duper Professional Camera Model 3" as "SDPC3" in the catalog and all, that "SDPC3" would, in my opinion, be an excellent choice for a primary key.

But that doesn't sound like what your colleagues want to do here. They want to take a product category, "camera", that of course no one expects to be unique, and then make it unique by tacking on a sequence number. This gives you the worst of both worlds: It's hard to generate, a long string which makes it slower to process, and it's still meaningless: no one is going to remember that "camera0002904" is the 3 megapixel camera with the blue case while "camera0002905" is the 4 megapixel camera with the red case. No one is going to consistently remember that sort of thing, anyway. So you're not going to use these values as useful display values to the user.

If you are absolutely forced to do something like this, I'd say make two fields: One for the category, and one for the sequence number. If they want them concatenated together for some display, fine. Preferably make the sequence number unique across categories so it can be the primary key by itself, but if necessary you can assign sequence numbers within the category. MySQL will do this automatically; most databases will require you to write some code to do it. (Post again if you want discussion on how.) Oh, and I wouldn't have anyone type in "camera" for the category. This should be a look-up table of legal values, and then post the primary key of this look-up table into the product record. Otherwise you're going to have "camera" and "Camera" and "camrea" and dozens of other typos and variations.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't do it like "camera0001"!** argue it out, that is a horrible design mistake.

try one of these:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization
- http://www.datamodel.org/NormalizationRules.html
- just google: **database normalization**

Each column in a database should only contain 1 piece of information.  Keep the ID and the type in different columns.  You can display them together if you wish, but do not store them the together!  You will have to constantly split them and make simple queries difficult.  The string will take a lot of space on disk and cache memory, if it is a FK it will waste space there too.

have a pure numeric auto column ID and a type column that is a foreign key to a table that contains a description, like:

Table1

```
YourID     int  auto id  PK
YourType   char(1)  fk
```

TypeTable

```
 YourType   char(1)  PK
 Description  varchar(100)
```

Table1

```
YourID  YourType   YourData....
1         C        xyz
2         C        abc
3         R        dffd
4         C        fg
```

TypeTable

```
YourType   Description
C          Camera
R          Radio
```

Comment: +1, avoid this design mistake.  use an auto integer and append "camera" to it (through code) if necessary

Comment: use an auto integer and append it to a string if you must elsewhere, but don't store the strings. Also, always use an auto id instead of something ugly like "total number of camera" +1, because the latter will subsequently break. Urge your colleagues to read up on referential integrity among other things,

Comment: But it seems that there are some people who argue that PK should a meaningful string, isn't it?

Comment: let me know in a year how much fun it is working with PKs like this and how slow your queries are.

Comment: Not at all.  But our DB designer definitely accepted the theory that PK should be "meaningful" string.

Comment: you changed my answer from "selected" to another that was basically the same answer, but I still hope you don't do it the "camera00001" way.  You seem to have a hangup on "meaningful" string.  If your data does not have a unique way to identity each row there is no shame in going for an INT id, it would be 1000 time better than "camera00001".  If your data does have a unique way to identity each row, look at that for the PK...

Answer (score 0):

Have a table with your serial number counters, increment it and insert your record.

OR

Set the Id to 'camera' + PAD((RIGHT(MAX(ID), 4) + 1), '0', 4)

Comment: Do not do this. Use auto-id instead. A separate serial-number counter or using a string key is a horrible idea.

Comment: You are right but sometimes you don't have choice... "just don't like arguing with my collegues"